# Average from error prone measurement samples without buffering

Tags: c, average, microcontroller, adc

I got a µC which measures temperature with of a sensor with an ADC. Due to various circumstances it can happen, that the reading is 0 (-30°C) or a impossible large Value (500-1500°C). I can't fix the reasons why these readings are so bad (time critical ISRs and sometimes a bad wiring) so I have to fix it with a clever piece of code.

I've come up with this (code gets called OVERSAMPLENR-times in a ISR):

```
#define OVERSAMPLENR 16 //read value 16 times
#define TEMP_VALID_CHANGE 0.15 //15% change in reading is possible
//float raw_tem_bed_value = <sum of all readings>;
//ADC = <AVR ADC reading macro>;
if(temp_count > 1) { //temp_count = amount of samples read, gets increased elsewhere
  float avgRaw = raw_temp_bed_value / temp_count;
  float diff = (avgRaw > ADC ? avgRaw - ADC : ADC - avgRaw) / (avgRaw == 0 ? 1 : avgRaw); //pulled out to shorten the line for SO
  if (diff > TEMP_VALID_CHANGE * ((OVERSAMPLENR - temp_count) / OVERSAMPLENR)) //subsequent readings have a smaller tollerance
    raw_temp_bed_value += avgRaw;
  else
    raw_temp_bed_value += ADC;
} else {
  raw_temp_bed_value = ADC;
}
```

Where `raw_temp_bed_value` is a static global and gets read and processed later, when the ISR got fired 16 times.

As you can see, I check if the difference between the current average and the new reading is less then 15%. If so I accept the reading, if not, I reject it and add the current average instead.
But this breaks horribly if the first reading is something impossible.

One solution I though of is:
In the last line the raw_temp_bed_value is reset to the first ADC reading. It would be better to reset this to `raw_temp_bed_value/OVERSAMPLENR`. So I don't run in a "first reading error".

Do you have any better solutions? I though of some solutions featuring a moving average and use the average of the moving average but this would require additional arrays/RAM/cycles which we want to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

I've often used something what I call rate of change to the sampling. Use a variable that represents how many samples it takes to reach a certain value, like 20. Then keep adding your sample difference to a variable divided by the rate of change. You can still use a threshold to filter out unlikely values.

```
float RateOfChange = 20;
float PreviousAdcValue = 0;
float filtered = FILTER_PRESET;

while(1)
{
    //isr gets adc value here        
    filtered = filtered + ((AdcValue - PreviousAdcValue)/RateOfChange);
    PreviousAdcValue = AdcValue;
    sleep();
}
```

Please note that this isn't exactly like a low pass filter, it responds quicker and the last value added has the most significance. But it will not change much if a single value shoots out too much, depending on the rate of change.

You can also preset the filtered value to something sensible. This prevents wild startup behavior.

It takes up to RateOfChange samples to reach a stable value. You may want to make sure the filtered value  isn't used before that by using a counter to count the number of samples taken for example. If the counter is lower than RateOfChange, skip processing temperature control.

For a more advanced (temperature) control routine, I highly recommend looking into PID control loops. These add a plethora of functionality to get a fast, stable response and keep something at a certain temperature efficiently and keep oscillations to a minimum. I've used the one used in the Marlin firmware in my own projects and works quite well.